# Intersection line not correct in PSTricks (3D) and warning "transparency ignored"

Tags: xetex, luatex, pstricks, 3d, pst-solides3d

Please look at hte following MWE, compiled in Plain XeTeX (or Plain LuaTeX):

```
\ifdefined\directlua \input luaotfload.sty \fi
\input pst-solides3d.tex

\psset{unit=1cm} 
\psset{viewpoint=50 30 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50} 
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint}
\pspicture[solidmemory](-7,-8)(7,8)
\defFunction[algebraic]{plane2}(u,v){0}{u}{v}%
\defFunction[algebraic]{hyperboloid}(u,v){(1+u^2)^0.5*cos(v)}{(1+u^2)^0.5 * sin(v)}{u}%
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree, linecolor=blue, base=-3 3 0 6.28,
   fillcolor=cyan,incolor=green, function=hyperboloid, ngrid=100 100,
   action=none,name=hyper1] 
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree, linecolor=blue, base=Pi neg Pi -3 3, fillcolor=red,
  function=plane2,ngrid=.2 .2,action=none,name=firstplane]
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=hyper1 firstplane,grid]
\endpspicture

\bye
```

1. The intersection line between the plane and the hyperboloid is ugly (not smooth). What's wrong here?
2. When I try to get transparent objects then I get a warning: "Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dNOSAFER". With MikTeX 21 transparency worked but after the update to MikTeX 22 the warning appeared. How to fix this?
3. When I compile this with Plain LuaTeX (and luapstricks) then I also get a warning "Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase' is not loaded." What is that?

[image]

**Edit:** With the help of user187802 I enabled transparency. But then the grid appears (and is intransparent) although I have deactivated it with the grid option. How can I fix that?

See:

```
\input pst-solides3d.tex

\psset{unit=1cm} 
\psset{viewpoint=50 30 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightintensity=1.2, opacity=.6} 
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint}
\pspicture[solidmemory](-7,-8)(7,8)
\defFunction[algebraic]{plane2}(u,v){0}{u}{v}%
\defFunction[algebraic]{hyperboloid}(u,v){(1+u^2)^0.5*cos(v)}{(1+u^2)^0.5 * sin(v)}{u}%
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree, base=-3 3 0 6.28,
   fillcolor=cyan, incolor=cyan, function=hyperboloid, ngrid=60 60,
   action=none,name=hyper1] 
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree, base=Pi neg Pi -3 3, fillcolor=red,
  function=plane2, action=none,name=firstplane, ngrid= 60 60]
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=hyper1 firstplane,grid]
\endpspicture

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: pdfmanagement-testphase is a latex package. It won't work with plaintex.

Comment: OK, so it will never work properly with Plain LuaTeX.

Comment: "never" is a grand word. You only need to transport the relevant part of the pdfmanagement code into plain to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree, linecolor=blue, 
         base=Pi neg Pi -3 3, fillcolor=red,
         function=plane2,ngrid=0.05 0.05,action=none,name=firstplane]
```

[image]

see also for `-dNOSAFER`  https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2021-March/046599.html

And here the same with transparency:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, now it looks good. But why is the second example not completely transparent? The grid is visible, but it shoud be invisible because of the `grid` option. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to edit my own question, not the answer. Can someone delete my mistake, please?

Comment: I deleted the comment ...

Comment: It is years ago that I looked into the code. As far as I remember, it is not possible to have transparency without a grid.